# more concise way of setting all drow downs to blank option

Tags: jquery

I have a way of resetting a certain group of selects on page back to blank option. Just wondering if more concise way of doing it?

**Markup**

```
<select id="test1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="one">One</option>
</select>
<select id="test2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var sel1 = $('#test1');
var sel2 = $('#test2');
$.each([sel1, sel2], function () {$(this).val('');}); //anymore concise?
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll get lots of answers for this, but I think you could use some overall help with JQuery. This might be something to take a look at:
http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2011/05/jquery-selectors-examples.html
or http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
$("select").val("");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms258v83/